# pgfplots with list and make fails on windows (mingw)

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external

System specs: MiKTeX 2.9, Windows 8.1, `-shell-escape` added, MinGW installed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
\tikzsetexternalprefix{tikz/}

\graphicspath{{./gfx/}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        {
            \tikzsetnextfilename{figure-line}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex` file `test.makefile` is created. I changed the `ALL_FIGURE_NAMES` to a hardcoded figure name due to Windows `make` problems that were pointed out on `stackexchange`:

```
ALL_FIGURE_NAMES=tikz/figure-line
ALL_FIGURES=$(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.pdf)

allimages: $(ALL_FIGURES)
    @echo All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.

FORCEREMAKE:

include $(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.dep)

%.dep:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@ # will be filled later.

tikz/figure-line.pdf: 
    pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/figure-line" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{test}"

tikz/figure-line.pdf: tikz/figure-line.md5
```

Now I run `mingw32-make -f .\test.makefile` and it fails:

```
.\test.makefile:9: figure-line.dep: No such file or directory
mkdir -p ./
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
.\test.makefile:12: recipe for target 'figure-line.dep' failed
mingw32-make: *** [figure-line.dep] Error 1
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is this a `mingw` related problem? Should I switch to `cygwin`?

Comment: It works with `cygwin`. I still have an error related to the `endfloat` package. Is there a way to delimit the preamble used for generating the figures? Something like `\EndPreamble`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem (building external `pgfplots` under `Windows` with `MinGW`) is not related to the `pgfplots` package (nor to the code from the `MWE`) but rather to the `make` tool that comes with `MinGW`. The `make` tool from `cygwin` builds everything fine with no changes to the code from the `MWE`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it turned out that it worked only when I started the bash-console of cygwin to run the make command with the `--login` option.

So I use the command

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -c "cd /cygdrive/c/<path>; make -f <file>.makefile"
```

to build the plots.